# How to fill only part of a curve plotted with a .dat file using pscustom?

Tags: pstricks, pscustom

I know how to use `pscustom` to fill the area between two curves but how can I fill only, say, a rectangle below part of a curve plotted with a .dat file?

What I did was to generate two .dat files, one with my curve and other with a line on x-axis, which I called the `groundData`.

```
\readdata{\data}{data.dat}
\readdata{\groundData}{groundData.dat}


\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,linestyle=none]{
\listplot[plotNo=2,plotNoMax=6]{\data}
\listplot[ChangeOrder]{\groundData}}
}
```

Since the `data.dat` file have information on several curves the `plotNo` and `plotNoMax` options help to pick the correct one. When I do this, instead of a rectangle below part of the curve (the part over the segment of line on the x-axis) I get two triangles with touching vertices as if the last point of `data.dat` was being connected to the first point in `groundData.dat`. The `changeorder` option was supposed to take care of this but it seems to have the same effect as if it was not there.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: We might try to help, if we had the data files and a full compilable code…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of the `\listplot` parameter:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\readdata\data{data.data}
\psset{xunit=12.5cm,yunit=0.2mm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.080,-30)(1,270)
\pstScalePoints(1,1){1000 div}{1000 div}
\psaxes[Dx=200,dx=2.5cm,Dy=100,ticksize=0 5pt,tickstyle=inner,
    subticks=10,ylabelFactor=\cdot10^3,dy=2cm](0,0)(1,250)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue,opacity=0.4,linestyle=none,linecap=2]{%
  \psline(0.2,0)(0.2,10)% 10 is only a guess
  \listplot[xStart=200,xEnd=800]{\data}
  \psline(0.8,10)(0.8,0)
}
\listplot[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue]{\data}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `linecap=2` there is drawn a straight line from (0.2,10) to the value
of the data. And the same for the right side from data end to (0.8,10)

The data file is part of your TeX installation. It uses values from
0..994 for x and 0..256500 for y. Should be simply adopted to your
data area.